# MongoDB: will index be used with $regex operator

Tags: mongodb

Let's say my `posts` collection has a `text` field with an index on it:

`db.posts.createIndex({ text: 1 })`,

I would like to confirm if the below query will use that index or not:

```
db.posts.find({ text: { $regex: 'value', $options: 'i' } })
```

I don't want to maintain an unused index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `db.posts.find({ text: { $regex: 'value', $options: 'i' } }).explain("executionStats")` and see for yourself. 
Index will be used, in the `executionStats` you will see **totalKeysExamined** and **totalDocsExamined**. It will search through all the keys but will retrieve only the affected docs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply